# WSL + Scons: No such file or directory

Tags: scons, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL and SCons for cross compiling with arm-none-eabi-gcc. When I try to build I get: "scons: *** [target] No such file or directory", where "target" is the name of the object file to build. The same build is working on our build machine (Arch Linux) and if I compile manually it also work fine. So obviously SCons can't find the source code, but why?

Comment: So where is your source code folder?

Comment: I have cloned my Git repo here: "/mnt/c/repo/". I've also tried to clone my repo in my Linux home folder "/home/<my name>/" but I got the same result

Comment: Can you paste the exact command line you are using when you run SCons? Also what version of SCons and what version of Python?

Comment: Here is the command line I'm using: "scons --site-dir=build/site_scons -j8 --max-drift=1 --implicit-deps-unchanged -Q CONFIG=config/config-XMC4500_F144x1024-release_wbl.cfg ENABLE_LOG=yes TOOLCHAIN=arm-gcc motor"

Comment: The SCons version is v3.0.1 and the Python version is 2.7.15rc1

Comment: The WSL distro is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that scons is not able to find 'sh' rather than the object file. Make sure that you aren't editing env['PATH'] anywhere in your build scripts?